# Proper If-Else in getting $_GET value and use in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a simple API that takes input from this route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::get('api/v1/ct/{dte?}', 'API\APIController@CTIntervalAPICall');
});
```

I've tried using different if-else method to see if an end_dte is supplemented in the URL. If so, it takes the dte as the starting date and the end_dte as the end date.

```
   public function CTIntervalAPICall(Request $dte)
    {
      $date = $dte->dte;
 //   $end_date = $dte->end_dte;
      $end_date = Input::get('end_dte');
      $element_language = $dte->language;
      $element_customer = $dte->customer;
      $element_contract = $dte->contract;
      $element_subcontract = $dte->subcontract;
      $element = $dte->element;
      $ct_interval= CTInterval::select()      
      if(input::has('end_dte')){
        ->where('dte', '>=', $date)
        ->where('dte', '<=', $end_date);
        }
      else {
        ->where('dte', $date);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['customer'])){
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('element_customer', $element_customer);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['contract'])){
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('element_contract', $element_contract);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['subcontract'])){
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('element_subcontract', $element_subcontract);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['language'])){
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('element_language', $element_language);
        }
        if(isset($_GET['element'])){
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('element', $element);
        }
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->get()->toArray();
      function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
          foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
              if( is_array($value) ) {
                  $key = 'Exception';
                  $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                  array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
              } else {
                  $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
              }
           }
      }
      $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><ctForecast></ctForecast>');
      array_to_xml($ct_interval,$xml_data);
      $result = $xml_data->asXML();
      return Response::make($result, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

It's supposed to use the >=$date as the starting date and <=$end_date as the end date IF end_dte is supplemented, otherwise it should only be =$date. But I'm running into an error. I'm wondering what's the correct way of doing this in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to control the operator using this:

```
 public function CTIntervalAPICall(Request $dte)
    {
      $date = $dte->dte;
      if(Input::get('end_dte')) {
        $end_date = Input::get('end_dte');
        $operator = '>=';
      }
      else {
        $operator = '=';
      }
      $element_language = $dte->language;
      $element_customer = $dte->customer;
      $element_contract = $dte->contract;
      $element_subcontract = $dte->subcontract;
      $element = $dte->element;
      $ct_interval= CTInterval::select()
        ->where('dte', $operator, $date);
        if(isset($_GET['end_dte'])){
        $ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('dte', '<=', $end_date);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No Laravel expert, but this syntax is purely not valid PHP Syntax

```
 $ct_interval= CTInterval::select()      
  if(input::has('end_dte')){
    ->where('dte', '>=', $date)
    ->where('dte', '<=', $end_date);
    }
  else {
    ->where('dte', $date);
    }
```

You may want to give us what the actual error is, although I pretty sure it's a Parse error.

I think you mean `$ct_interval = $ct_interval->where('dte', '>=', $date)` instead of just randomly supplying arrows in your code.

Two rows below you have used it the right way. Just terminate the `select` statement and add where clauses to the already created variable.